# Opentok error in rails app, "OT is not defined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opentok

I am getting the error "OT is not defined" error in my ruby on rails app:[image]

The API key, session_id and token has proper values.

I have included "gem 'opentox'" in my gemfile and ran 'bundle install'.
Not sure how else to initialize OT.

Show.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var apiKey = '<%= @api_key %>';
  var sessionId = '<%= @room.session_id %>';
  var token = '<%= @token %>';
</script>

<div id="videos">
  <div id="publisher"></div>
  <div id="subscribers"></div>
</div>

<script>
  // Handling all of our errors here by alerting them
  function handleError(error) {
    if (error) {
       alert(error.message);
       }
    }

    initializeSession();

    function initializeSession() {
      var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);

      // Subscribe to a newly created stream
      session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {
      session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber', {
        insertMode: 'append',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
      }, handleError);
      });

     // Create a publisher
    var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', {
      insertMode: 'append',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
    }, handleError);

   // Connect to the session
   session.connect(token, function(error) {
   // If the connection is successful, publish to the session
   if (error) {
      handleError(error);
    } else {
    session.publish(publisher, handleError);
    }
    });
   }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the opentok script tag to show.html.erb, I am able to overcome this issue:
    `<script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js"></script>`

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. 

Glad you found the solution. You can find more information on the OpenTok JS SDK here: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/

Answer (score 0):

OT is an object of opentok which used for init session, destroy session or etc. If you have to use OT object than you must have to cdn in `application.html.erb` so that this OT object can be used in each page
You just have to put a cdn in head tag of `application.html.erb`

`<script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js"></script>`